# Xpath one node and next node in single object

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a confusing problem. I have a simple HTML:

```
 <p>Paragraph 1</p>
 <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
 </ul>
 <p>Paragraph 4</p>
 <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
 </ul>
 <p>Paragraph 3</p>
 <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
 </ul>
```

My goal is to select `p` and `ul` in a single XPATH object to iterate over it.
I tried the `union |` operator but this returns me 2 element list (python) so I can just `.join` but when I iterate over it this is raw `str` instead of XPATH selector object.
The final output per object should be:

```
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: YOu mean you just want to extract the element text from the <p> and all its <li> children?

Comment: Yes this should be in single xpath object. before call extract() method. I use xpath 2.0

Comment: Could you add your Python code snippet so that the effect can be reproduced?